# Generating extremely large images in C#

Tags: c#, .net, memory, bitmap

I need to generate some large graphs whose width and height can go up to millions of pixels in size. Please note that I do NOT want to scale down the image. Each point must represent one pixel.

Now using the Bitmap and Graphics objects, this is very much possible if I split the image into smaller squares but it is painfully slow.

I already calculate the pixel RGB values so was wondering if there is a way to create a byte array with these values and manually save them as an uncompressed BMP format file instead of dealing with the Bitmap class and the drawing functions of the Graphics class.

I am comfortable with unsafe code if that helps to speed up the process.

Comment: Do you mean "millions of pixels" total, like 1024 x 1024 is about a million pixels, or do you mean the *dimensions* are 1000000 x 1000000? If the latter, where do you plan to store the terabytes of image data?

Comment: I know I'm not helping but it would be what.. 1 Terabyte / image?

Comment: 1 TB per image only if it's 256 color. 24 bit color would be 3 TB/image.

Comment: (1) What is your use case?  [Different graphic file formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_graphics_file_formats) are used for specific business applications (e.g. [DICOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DICOM#DICOM_data_format) for Radiology systems).  (2) If this is general purpose, are you certain that vectors would not be a better solution?

Comment: What program do you plan to use to *read* such an image?

Comment: @KevinHsu: That's the easy part, I can easily roll out my own viewer that loads up parts of the image on demand.

Comment: @DavidYaw: Yes, in my case I could do with black and white as well actually.

Comment: But then why not break it up into separate images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(While there is good question if anything will be able to read such files...)

[BMP format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) is very simple - you can write it directly to disk (I'd recommend avoiding building huge file in memory unless you have other reasons to do so). There is a fixed-size header and then (for 24bpp) sequences of colors aligned on some width. Assuming you can pick width you will not even need to add any padding - just rows of colors for each pixel.

Comment: As for reading, I can build a simple application that loads and displays parts of the image with mouse interaction. Thanks for your 24bpp tip. Although after Jordan's suggestion, I'm considering building my own rendering client for vectors which should be pretty easy to patch up.

Answer (score 3):

If you're displaying graphs, why don't you use a technology like SVG that can be rendered on the fly with very little processing power, yet can scale to near-infinite sizes thanks to vector expansion?

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing how to generate an SVG representation if there are good rendering clients out there.

Comment: What is your client platform? Web? Desktop? Mobile? All of these?

Comment: .NET c# desktop app. I'm, thinking about rolling out my own client. Not SVG of course, just an interactive tool to allow panning and zooming using my own vector data.

Comment: Yeah, I think you'll be much more successful deploying widely if you can avoid large bitmap images. Here's a C# SVG renderer. There are others. http://sharpvectors.codeplex.com/